# Finding the bearing of an reflected ray formed at a square from the center

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a square. X is the midpoint, a ray emerges from X at a random counterclockwise bearing T, and hits a side of the square, how do I find the counterclockwise bearing of the reflected ray.

Since the incident angle = reflected angle, the emergent ray has a bearing of 270 +x, , I know x can be found by subtracting the other two angles (90 and T), but i struggle to find a formula that works for all instances (point E below can be on any point of the square) [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L50CG.png)